# Detect if user is connected to firebase app

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to implement an "isActive" feature on my app that is built using firebase firestore. I am using firebase functions along with authentication in my React App.

Is there a way of detecting if the user is "active" or "inActive" on my app by triggering a cloud function when they login or disconnect to the app?
If i can determine this i would store the value in firestore and handle it in the frontend to display a UI.
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you define as being active. I.e. how does writing to Firestore when they sign-in equate to them being active? --- Also: if you're looking for a presence system, did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence?

Answer (score 0):

I see two aspects to the question here:

1. Auth state: You want to track the logged-in duration of the user.
2. Focus state: You want to track when the user is active on the app.

For #1, you will have to listen to the auth state changes, and you may also want to change your auth state persistence strategy accordingly. From https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence:

| Enum | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL | 'local' | Indicates that the state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state. Note that Firebase Auth web sessions are single host origin and will be persisted for a single domain only. |
| firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION | 'session' | Indicates that the state will only persist in the current session or tab, and will be cleared when the tab or window in which the user authenticated is closed. Applies only to web apps. |
| firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE | 'none' | Indicates that the state will only be stored in memory and will be cleared when the window or activity is refreshed. |

```
import { getAuth, setPersistence, signInWithRedirect, inMemoryPersistence, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    // In memory persistence will be applied to the signed in Google user
    // even though the persistence was set to 'none' and a page redirect
    // occurred.
    return signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });

You don't need a cloud function for th
```

For #2, you might want to check out this blog. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/validate-your-apps-session-on-focus-892f610f7e23.

```
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export function WindowFocusHandler() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("focus", onFocus)
    }
  }, [])

  const onFocus = () => dispatch(session.effects.checkSessionOnFocus(location))

  return <></>
}
```

The Focus event on a window might get triggered more often if it is a browser app. Depending on what you want to achieve, both things should be possible in
your front-end code without the need for cloud functions. Although, you might opt to code the logic as a firebase function and invoke it from your react code when onFocus.